# 159h vs 160h breaks override relative time in time range of table in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have scrape data in Prometheus every hour around the 43 minute mark for the past around 5 days. I would like to display the hourly scrape events from the past week in a table in Grafana. In the table, when I set the **Override relative time** option in Time range to 6 days, the table properly displays all my hourly data, since I only have 5 days of data. However, when I set the override to 7 days, it only shows me data from the first day, and not even all the data from that day.

I tried narrowing the override down, and found that the threshold is 159h vs 160h. When it's 159h, the table works as expected, but when it's 160h, suddenly the table breaks. Why does increasing the time range by 1 hour cause the table to break, especially considering no additional data is even being considered?